# Firebase Storage Excepiton

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

I have this error:

```
020-06-24 11:51:21.583 11387-11387/com.example.silk E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    User does not have permission to access this object.
     Code: -13021 HttpResult: 403
2020-06-24 11:51:21.585 11387-11387/com.example.silk E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.serverStateValid(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:331)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.shouldContinue(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:300)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:221)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 403,    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"  }}
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:433)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:450)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:441)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:272)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:286)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:70)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:62)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:467)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:268)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:216)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@19.1.1:1072) 
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919) 
2020-06-24 11:51:21.654 11387-11387/com.example.silk E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView re turned.
```

This is how I have the Firebase Storage Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And that's how I update the user's profile

```
final StorageReference fileRef=strorageProfilePictureRef.child(Prevalent.currentonlineUser.getPhone() + ".jpg");
            uploadTask=fileRef.putFile(imageUri);

            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {

                    if(!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return fileRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Uri downloadUrl=task.getResult();
                        myUrl=downloadUrl.toString();

                        DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

                        HashMap<String,Object> userMap=new HashMap<>(); ////stocheaza multe date
                        userMap.put("name", fullNameEditText.getText().toString());
                        userMap.put("address", addressEditText.getText().toString());
                        userMap.put("phoneOrder", userPhoneEditText.getText().toString());
                        userMap.put("image", myUrl);
                        ref.child(Prevalent.currentonlineUser.getPhone()).updateChildren(userMap); 

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        startActivity(new Intent(SettingsActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile information updated successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

And it always goes with the Toast message `Error`, without updating the user's profile.

Alongside the user's profile image, I update also the name, phone number and address but these things work if I do not try to change the picture.

Can you tell me what I need to change in order to be able to change every field?

Answer (score 1):

change this rule
Anyone can read or write As Public

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

in your case below allowed only authenticated users can read or write  check the user is trying to reach is authenticated otherwise use the rule I typed above.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

you can use this that grants a user access to a node matching their user ID

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    // Files look like: "user/<UID>/path/to/file.txt"
    match /user/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

===========================

Use what your app needs to use as privacy.